# function should return items with the same property into an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object with 2 people and i want the function to return an array of all the people with the same property.

```
const people = {'Steven': ['football', 'hockey'], 'Maria': ['writing', 'swimming']}
```

the current function looks like this without any further progress:

```
function people(interests, interest) { return [] }
```

i want the function to check if i for example logs 'swimming' , it should print out Maria

Comment: Alright, what have you tried already ? Could you also give an example of the expected result of said function ?

Comment: And desired output!

Comment: So WHAT did you try? We are not a homework writing service. Break it up into steps and figure out each step. First step, figure out how to loop over the object. Second step figure out how to find a match in an array.  Third step, how do you add the name to an array? It is really simple when you think about it in parts.

Comment: Writing an almost empty function isn't an attempt.

Comment: **Clue:** `reduce` `Object.keys` `some` `(:` go ahead, and if you got stuck, come back and we will be glad to help you!

Comment: thanks, that should be enough for me to figure out. I never asked for a copy + paste method........

Comment: The problem is that you actually did. Because by watching few basic tutorials that would not take longer than hour, you would be able to do this kind of stuff easily on your own.

Comment: filter would be ok for the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```js
const people = {'Steven': ['football', 'hockey'], 'Maria': ['writing', 'swimming']};

let getCommomProps = (arr, prop) => {
    return Object.keys(arr).filter((key) => {
        return arr[key].includes(prop);
    }, 0);
};

console.log(getCommomProps(people, 'football'));
```

Comment: thanks you, i was stuck on the Object.keys forever and never knew what i was gonna do with the outcome. Now i understand.

Comment: Hi @ssenn if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` to evaluate the objects and accumulate the matches into an array.

The function `includes` is used to validate if a specific interest exists into the array of people.

*This approach returns the whole object which matched with a specific interest.*

```js
const people = {'Steven': ['football', 'hockey'], 'Maria': ['writing', 'swimming']},
      interest = "swimming",
      result = Object.keys(people).reduce((a, name) => {
        if (people[name].includes(interest)) a.push({[name]: people[name]});
        return a;
      }, []);
      
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```